# Macbook Pro 2010 crashes after waking up and usually when launching a Google Search in Chrome

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, crash, graphics, kernel-panic

I've got issues with my MBP which seem to be persistent, even after replacing the logic board for supposedly one without hardware issues. There are some typical instances when my macbook pro fails (crashes):

1. After waking up and I open up an app, e.g. Chrome and start typing in the search/location bar.
2. Just randomly (less so) and often in Chrome when I open up a page or Google something.

In addition, my battery was replaced twice and again it shows Service battery and has issues - e.g. a sudden drop in the percentage from 45% to 7% and overall short battery life.

Can anyone discover anything that could lead to a solution to this problem in the panic report below? My hunch is the graphics card or logic board or both..

```
Anonymous UUID:       F36B7D3C-A623-C356-8396-BA8B2C3339EB

Thu Aug  8 21:54:59 2019

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff7f9d7628d7): "GPU Panic: mux-regs 3 3 7f 0 0 0 severity 3 WS-ready 1 switch-state 0 IG FBs 0 EG FBs 1:3 power-state 0 3D idle HDA idle system-state 1 power-level 20:20 connect-change 0 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00100c80: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xd2000000 0xffffff913b253000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P2/4\n"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.20.14/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:170
Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff91297baf70 : 0xffffff801c46e1c6 
0xffffff91297bafc0 : 0xffffff801c596a74 
0xffffff91297bb000 : 0xffffff801c588d44 
0xffffff91297bb070 : 0xffffff801c4201e0 
0xffffff91297bb090 : 0xffffff801c46dc3c 
0xffffff91297bb1c0 : 0xffffff801c46d9fc 
0xffffff91297bb220 : 0xffffff7f9d7628d7 
0xffffff91297bb280 : 0xffffff7f9e2a6441 
0xffffff91297bb340 : 0xffffff7f9e3721ca 
0xffffff91297bb380 : 0xffffff7f9f3934ff 
0xffffff91297bb3e0 : 0xffffff7f9f392dbe 
0xffffff91297bb480 : 0xffffff7f9f38b101 
0xffffff91297bb6f0 : 0xffffff7f9f38b2d1 
0xffffff91297bb7e0 : 0xffffff7f9e34b465 
0xffffff91297bb860 : 0xffffff7f9e27d1b4 
0xffffff91297bb910 : 0xffffff7f9e2823be 
0xffffff91297bb9d0 : 0xffffff7f9e2aae23 
0xffffff91297bbbc0 : 0xffffff7f9e2acc7b 
0xffffff91297bbcb0 : 0xffffff7f9e52a34b 
0xffffff91297bbd20 : 0xffffff7f9e52a499 
0xffffff91297bbd40 : 0xffffff7f9e527d84 
0xffffff91297bbda0 : 0xffffff7f9e52157b 
0xffffff91297bbde0 : 0xffffff7f9e4e1192 
0xffffff91297bbe30 : 0xffffff7f9e4e149e 
0xffffff91297bbe60 : 0xffffff7f9e4d1b99 
0xffffff91297bbeb0 : 0xffffff7f9e4cf645 
0xffffff91297bbed0 : 0xffffff801ca9a075 
0xffffff91297bbf30 : 0xffffff801ca987e2 
0xffffff91297bbf70 : 0xffffff801ca97e0c 
0xffffff91297bbfa0 : 0xffffff801c41f557 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.20.14)[AF0A4CC9-B942-3C2B-90E3-665D518669A1]@0xffffff7f9d754000->0xffffff7f9d766fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.20.14)[5BC4ABF1-C918-3EA6-86CE-E39D64031E34]@0xffffff7f9d715000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[95DA39BB-7C39-3742-A2E5-86C555E21D67]@0xffffff7f9d15b000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[D91E9813-9717-31B8-BFE5-2F3A00F375F3]@0xffffff7f9cc94000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(519.21)[E5B53C5D-BF6E-3D72-9091-A80DFE5426C9]@0xffffff7f9d3f0000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.20.14)[D3CF5F89-2DA6-3F73-995D-F5DDE191E192]@0xffffff7f9d705000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.4)[F8258F0F-61AD-30F4-BDD5-B18CCAAE535A]@0xffffff7f9e255000->0xffffff7f9e4bdfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[D91E9813-9717-31B8-BFE5-2F3A00F375F3]@0xffffff7f9cc94000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(519.21)[8E0EE518-0D53-38C0-B308-2C6CD9EC5B7B]@0xffffff7f9d72c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(519.21)[E5B53C5D-BF6E-3D72-9091-A80DFE5426C9]@0xffffff7f9d3f0000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla(10.0.4)[5DCF031B-F81F-32A3-ADCD-18E16EAC7CF0]@0xffffff7f9f2f2000->0xffffff7f9f59afff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.4)[F8258F0F-61AD-30F4-BDD5-B18CCAAE535A]@0xffffff7f9e255000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[D91E9813-9717-31B8-BFE5-2F3A00F375F3]@0xffffff7f9cc94000
         com.apple.GeForceTesla(10.0.4)[14EDD414-E707-3CC3-BFA5-FDFA902BF7ED]@0xffffff7f9e4c9000->0xffffff7f9e587fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[D91E9813-9717-31B8-BFE5-2F3A00F375F3]@0xffffff7f9cc94000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(519.21)[8E0EE518-0D53-38C0-B308-2C6CD9EC5B7B]@0xffffff7f9d72c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(519.21)[E5B53C5D-BF6E-3D72-9091-A80DFE5426C9]@0xffffff7f9d3f0000
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.4)[F8258F0F-61AD-30F4-BDD5-B18CCAAE535A]@0xffffff7f9e255000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
17G5019

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Thu Dec 20 21:47:19 PST 2018; root:xnu-4570.71.22~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 4A5298BF-709E-37DF-B7F0-4298065CC266
Kernel slide:     0x000000001c200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801c400000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801c300000
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 11379603801864
last loaded kext at 7349848193659: com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme 3 (addr 0xffffff7f9fbde000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 7559246802398: com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme   3 (addr 0xffffff7f9fbde000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.37
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    131
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   281.52
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.20.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.GeForceTesla  10.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   281.52
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   10.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.7f12
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.20.14
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 10.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    211
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AGDCBacklightControl   3.20.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  353
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.50.6
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 439.70.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  254
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 254
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  748.51.0
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.3.1
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.21.30
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329.50.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 220.50.1
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   183
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   220.50.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 683.1
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   680.15
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   10.0.4
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    10.0.4
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 281.52
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    526
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   211.15
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.20.14
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.9
com.apple.driver.



EOF

System Profile:
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Thunderbolt Bus: 
Boot Volume File System Type: apfs
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x04CB, 0x4D4946344432433038374B5A312020202020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x0198, 0x48503533363732372D4834312D454C442020
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Built-in iSight
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 840 Series, 250,06 GB
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MK5055GSXF, 500,11 GB
Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM 96.0.0.0.0, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 2,66 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.58f15
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.102.30)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.7f12, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
```

Battery info

```
Battery Information:

  Model Information:
  Serial Number:    D861015004NDGDL3T
  Manufacturer: SMP
  Device Name:  bq20z451
  Pack Lot Code:    0
  PCB Lot Code: 0
  Firmware Version: 2
  Hardware Revision:    00aa
  Cell Revision:    2
  Charge Information:
  Charge Remaining (mAh):   3971
  Fully Charged:    Yes
  Charging: No
  Full Charge Capacity (mAh):   3971
  Health Information:
  Cycle Count:  118
  Condition:    Service Battery
  Battery Installed:    Yes
  Amperage (mA):    0
  Voltage (mV): 12601

System Power Settings:

  AC Power:
  System Sleep Timer (Minutes): 10
  Disk Sleep Timer (Minutes):   10
  Display Sleep Timer (Minutes):    10
  Wake on AC Change:    No
  Wake on Clamshell Open:   Yes
  Wake on LAN:  Yes
  Current Power Source: Yes
  Display Sleep Uses Dim:   Yes
  GPUSwitch:    2
  Hibernate Mode:   3
  PrioritizeNetworkReachabilityOverSleep:   0
  Battery Power:
  System Sleep Timer (Minutes): 10
  Disk Sleep Timer (Minutes):   10
  Display Sleep Timer (Minutes):    2
  Wake on AC Change:    No
  Wake on Clamshell Open:   Yes
  Display Sleep Uses Dim:   Yes
  GPUSwitch:    2
  Hibernate Mode:   3
  Reduce Brightness:    Yes

Hardware Configuration:

  UPS Installed:    No

AC Charger Information:

  Connected:    Yes
  ID:   0x0100
  Wattage (W):  85
  Revision: 0x0000
  Family:   0x00ba
  Serial Number:    0x0060d713
  Charging: No
```

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200553 Has a step by step guide to isolate causes. Please update after the same. And best way to avoid kernel panics is to avoid(if possible) the cause:). As per battery, please post the info in about this Mac -> system report-> hardware -> power -> battery.

Comment: I've updated the battery info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see from your panic report that this is a mid-2010 15" MacBook Pro. Unfortunately, this model was prone to having problems with its dedicated graphics card and while Apple did have an extended repair program for this model, that extra coverage has now ended.

However, there are a few things you can do to minimise the problem.

**gfxCardStatus**

Many users have found that using [gfxCardStatus](https://gfx.io/) will reduce these issues most of the time. My experience with many users is that versions 1.8.1 and 2.1 seem to be the best for your particular model MBP, even though more recent versions fixed a number of bugs.

So, I’d like you to give [version 1.8.1](https://gfx.io/downloads/gfxCardStatus-1.8.1.zip) a go for a while and see how you go. If you’re not happy with that, then try [version 2.1](https://gfx.io/downloads/gfxCardStatus-2.1.zip) instead.

NOTE: Unfortunately, there were two distinct issues that affected your particular model of MBP. gfxCardStatus was designed to address a hardware problem that occurs on a number of models, including yours. However, your model was also prone to being affected by a software issue that was unique to your model. If your model is affected by that as well, then [version 2.3](http://gfx.io/downloads/gfxCardStatus-2.3.zip) may be a better choice.  So, in summary, I would start with 1.8.1 and see how you go. If you’re not happy, then try 2.1. Then go to 2.3 if you're still not satisfied. **Do not try any other versions for your model MBP!**

**Google Chrome**

I actually wouldn't use Google Chrome on this machine, but if you really need to then there’s actually a setting in Google Chrome that may help you:

1. Go to Chrome > Preferences
2. Scroll down to the bottom
3. Click on *Advanced*
4. Scroll down to the *System* heading
5. Disable the *Use hardware acceleration when available* option

**macOS**

There are a couple of things you can do within macOS:

- You’re probably already aware of this one – but for your MBP you should have an additional setting under System Preferences > Energy Saver for Automatic graphics switching. Playing with this and the other Graphics option (for better battery life) may be useful.
- Now this one is not so obvious:

  1. Go to System Preferences
  2. Click on Accessibility
  3. Select Display (in the left-hand column)
  4. On the right-hand side, tick the Reduce transparency and Reduce motion boxes.
  5. Exit System Preferences

Basically, to draw/display transparency and show motion in the GUI (windows etc), it needs a lot of graphics power. Not a good idea for your MBP I’m afraid.

Comment: thanks! one question: is the 'reduce transparency' box ticked on or off? I turned it off for now.

Comment: You want to actually tick the box so that macOS reduces the use of transparency in its GUI.

Comment: I had 'Reduce motion' and 'Reduce transparency' both ticked on before, so that wasn't preventing the problem to occur unfortunately.

Comment: @ThiemeHennis It’s not so much that these settings will prevent the problem on their own. What we’re trying to do here is reduce as much as possible the need for your MBP to have to utilise the discrete GPU - so anything that reduces the amount of graphics processing will help in achieving that. That’s the same reason we’re disabling the hardware acceleration option in Chrome. Likewise, if you happen to use Photoshop there’s a setting we can change there too.

Comment: By the way @ThiemeHennis , if your battery continues to have problems it’s most likely a totally separate issue. Your best bet would be to reset your SMC. See: https://support.apple.com/HT201295

Comment: ok thanks. helpful comments. By the way - the setting in Gfx should be dynamic switching? Or should I use either Intel or NVidia only?

Comment: You want to avoid as much as possible the NVIDIA GPU being used, so my recommendation would be to use Intel only **and** to take the steps in my answer re Chrome etc.

Comment: ah yes. sorry, I had disabled the Chrome setting on hardware acceleration before. thanks for your help. I will keep you posted in a few weeks. Right now I have approx. one crash per day.

Comment: Yes, please do. And don't forget if gfxCardStatus v1.8.1 doesn't meet your needs, then try v2.1. And, only if **both** those versions make no difference would I try v2.3. Don't try any other versions for your model MBP. All the best! :)

Comment: regarding the crashes: so far so good! I think indeed it's the NVidia card that causes issues. Need to work on the battery issue now.

Comment: ok, now a couple of weeks along: avoiding the NVIDIA card works (with Gfx status version 1.8.8 as recommended). So the answer is correct. Thanks!

Comment: That's great! :) So glad it's working so much better for you now!