# MacBook Pro immediately shuts down when disconnected from charger, auto starts when opening MacBook, even after shutdown

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, shutdown

I am running macOS 10.14.6 on a late 2013 MacBook Pro.  The system immediately shuts down when the charger is unplugged.  Oddly, even after intentionally shutting down the computer, it auto-starts when I open the lid.

I reset the PRAM and SMC, which didn't help.

This began several weeks ago when the system shut down for no apparent reason.  When I restarted, the system date was way off.  I reset it to auto detect the date. I could still operate under battery power, but it would shut down long before the battery was drained.

Now it will not operate on the battery at all.  After this random shutdown the battery condition was displaying Replace Soon. Now it displays Replace Now.  Cycle count is 194.  System information shows that the battery is not charging, even though plugged in.  For several months now I have noticed that the case will sometimes get very hot to the touch above the keyboard at times.  I installed Macs Fan Control and verified both fans are working properly.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: [Macbook Pro 2010 crashes after waking up and usually when launching a Google Search in Chrome](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366555/macbook-pro-2010-crashes-after-waking-up-and-usually-when-launching-a-google-sea/366559#366559)

Comment: Update: My system just shutdown while plugged in. I plugged in a different charger, restarted, and now the battery shows 0%, not charging.  I then reset my PRAM 5 times. Battery status still shows Replace now; not charging.

Comment: I've edited your question as this site works best when each question is about one issue. But please feel free to ask another question about the second issue.

Comment: @BluesJunkie As per my answer, you need to replace the battery. Resetting the NVRAM (what you're calling PRAM) is irrelevant, but resetting the SMC is worth trying again just to make sure you've reset it properly. But, the reality is your battery is just showing its age.

Answer (score 1):

Your battery is old even if it still has a low cycle count. You might even have a battery that has been damaged in production. In all cases you should not continue using your MacBook in this condition. The battery could start producing gases, inflating and destroy it in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You could reset the SMC again, making sure you refer to [Apple's documentation](https://support.apple.com/HT201295) to double-check you've reset it properly.

However, since the SMC reset hasn't resolved this (as one would expect), your battery status is most likely key to your problem.

While MacBook Pro batteries have a life expectancy at or around 1,000 cycles, it's not uncommon for batteries to exceed or fall short of this number; as every user is different in terms of what they use their computers for and how/when they're using AC power etc. So the 1,000 cycles is just an estimation of how long it can last. But, in your case, it appears that time is the biggest issue (i.e. while your battery has done less than 200 cycles, it likely needs replacing because of its age).

So, if resetting the SMC doesn't work, it's time to replace your battery.

Answer (score 0):

Take it to an Apple Store soon!!

The Late 2013 MBP is still supported by Apple, but the Early 2013 is not (so the Late 13 model is likely to go out of support soon.) A new battery will give your Mac years more life -- they actually replace the whole top case, including keyboard and trackpad.