# how to reduce Normal Boot's graphical performance (so that it copies Safe Boot's)?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, catalina, performance

I am [having an issue recently](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/378636/150109) which causes my MacBook Pro 2015, 15", to spontaneously (and randomly?) shut down.

These shut downs do not happen in Recovery Mode or Safe Boot.

Here is my MacBook information:

> **MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)**
>   **Processor** 2.2 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7
>   **Memory** 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
>   **Graphics** Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB

Temporarily, before I am able to identify and fix the root cause, I would like to continue using my laptop.

I suspect the reason the shut downs don't happen in Safe Boot is because its [graphical performance is limited](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203889). I am therefore hopeful that similarly reducing Normal Boot's graphical performance will help me use my MacBook again.

I would like to at least try, as it may be further helpful to identify the root of the problem anyway.

How can I limit Normal Boot's graphical performance?

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific as to which model - IG or DG most importantly, if you have a GPU fail [which could be likely]

Comment: @Tetsujin I have added some information to the question. Let me know if you still need more (I don't actually know what IG and DG are)

Comment: There's 'Integrated' & 'Dual' Graphics. tbh, I'm not certain exactly how each reports itself to the user. Maybe try Everymac's identifier page - https://everymac.com/mac-identification/index-how-to-identify-my-mac.html

Comment: Have you tried a clean install or booting from an external drive? That would at least rule in or out any software issue on the drive itself.

Comment: see some it here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366555/macbook-pro-2010-crashes-after-waking-up-and-usually-when-launching-a-google-sea/366559#366559